# Can I change the stack size limits from within the program?

Tags: haskell, stack, ghc

I can configure the maximum stack size of a GHC compiled Haskell program by passing `+RTS -Kn` to it, where `n` is some number.

Is there a way to change this setting from within the program?

(I’d like to benchmark stack consumption of various functions, and hence try to run it with various limits, catching the `StackOverflow` exception.)

Comment: There seems to be no API for doing this, but it should be possible to modify `RtsFlags.GcFlags.maxStkSize` from CMM code or via FFI. I've no idea how safe that is (increasing the limit is probably fine, decreasing probably not).

Comment: Safe API for doing this would be indeed a great addition to GHC.

Why not to open a bug?

For now you might want to use `-with-rtsopts` to define it at compile time for sure.

Comment: Not sure; in light of https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8189  (no stack size limit by default) this might actually be irrelevant for most users.

Comment: You could re-exec yourself when argv doesn’t contain some magic flag, with +RTS -Kn and that magic flag added. (I do that trick in shell scripts all the time (especially prepending sudo), and in C every once in a while.) Would be specific to Unix then, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time has answered this with: „No“