# Limit default stack size in GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

In [a recent question about stack overflows in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20313059/1463507) kosmikus said the default stack size of GHCi is 512 MB. I would much rather have a smaller stack size, like 2 MB or something, because if I go beyond that, in almost all cases, it will be because of an error on my part. My system doesn't have very much RAM, so a stack size of 512 MB sometimes causes some crazy swapping and slowness when I make a mistake in the code.

**Is there a way to limit the default stack size of GHCi, in the `.ghci` file or somewhere else?**

I'm aware that I should be able to create an

```sh
alias ghci='ghci +RTS -K2M -RTS'
```

as a last resort, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: I think the alias is probably not a bad option if you really want that. Note that the `ghci` binary is actually the same as the `ghc` binary, and limiting its stack size means you're limiting the stack size during compilation as well. Setting it to a really small value can yield errors coming from the compilation. For example, running `ghci +RTS -K1K` immediately crashes.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19950074/can-i-change-the-stack-size-limits-from-within-the-program

Comment: @MikhailGlushenkov Not this time! I don't want to do this for every program, I want it to be the default for all programs.

Comment: @kqr My understanding is that you need to find a way to modify `RtsFlags.GcFlags.maxStkSize` from a running Haskell program to be able to set stack size from `.ghci`. Which is the same as the linked question.

Comment: @MikhailGlushenkov Oh, clever workaround. I'll look into it.